# adding dynamic buttons wpf in a wrappanel

Tags: c#, wpf, button, dynamic, wrappanel

I am trying to display buttons dynamically on the screen in a wrap panel so that they are laid our nicely without any scrollbars. I have the markup as below, but the scrollbars appear for some reason. how do we make the scrollbar not appear and the buttons laid out without any scrollbars.

```
<ListBox x:Name="ItemsListBox"  >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ToggleButton Content="{Binding Name}" Click="Click" MinWidth="120" MinHeight="70" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel></WrapPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

What control is your `ListBox` inside?  Most often the problem you descrive is caused by the *parent* control allowing the `ListBox` to grow.

You can prove whether this is the problem by setting an explicit `Width="200"` on your `ListBox` and testing what happens.  If it wraps, then the problem is the `ListBox`'s parent.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
```

to you containers.

Answer (score 0):

This does it what I was trying to achieve.

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="ListBox" Grid.Row="5"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ToggleButton Content="{Binding Name}" MinWidth="120" MinHeight="50" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16" Margin="5"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```